# Reverse (or toggle) animation and fade

Tags: jquery, css, animation

## What I have:

A basic `<ul>` that animates and simultaneously fades in when a `<a>` is clicked.

```
$("a.language_selected").on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //$("ul.language_dropdown").fadeToggle("slow");
    $('ul.language_dropdown').fadeIn({queue: false, duration: 'fast'});
    $('ul.language_dropdown').animate({ top: "58px"}, 'fast');
});
```

## What I need:

I now need to reverse (or toggle) the fade in and animation of the `<ul>` when the same `<a>` is clicked a second time. Furthermore a second `<a>`, contained within the `<ul>`, serving the exact same purpose as the first `<a>`, is being used as a cancel/close button.

## My question:

I've browsed through various similar StackOverflow questions however many are over several years old. What is the most modern and least verbose means of reversing (or toggling) the fade in and animation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The modern way is to use CSS. **I would strongly suggest using CSS transitions.** But if you want to use jQuery's animations:

```
$('ul.language_dropdown').fadeOut(...);
```

If you need a way to identify whether it is visible or not, just add a class to it:

```
$('ul.language_dropdown')
    .fadeIn({queue: false, duration: 'fast'})
    .animate({ top: "58px"}, 'fast')
    .addClass('language_dropdown_visible');
```

And then in your event handler, check if the class exists, and animate as necessary.

BTW: Fade in is usually just opacity, so you can put the two animating properties together:

```
$( 'ul.language_dropdown' ).animate({
    top: 58,
    opacity: 1
}, 400);
```

---

### Use CSS transitions

These are faster and cleaner than jQuery animations, and keeps your styling and logic seperate:

For your CSS (add the styles if you already have styling for these elements):

```
ul.language_dropdown {
    opacity: 0;
    top: 0;
    transition: all 400ms; /* Or opacity 400ms, top 400ms if you have other changing properties */
}
ul.language_dropdown.language_dropdown_visible {
    opacity: 0;
    top: 58px;
}
```

In your JS:

```
$("a.language_selected").on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('ul.language_dropdown').toggleClass('language_dropdown_visible');
});
```

That's it! Super clean, concise and organised, no worrying about half-states and glitchy animations, and modern, performant code that allows the browser to optimise.

Comment: I have no problem using CSS instead of jQuery providing it achieves the same result without limitation.

Comment: This is a great a solution based on the question I've asked. In foresight, the only limitation I conceive of is [easing](http://easings.net/). E.g. Easings like easeOutBounce [can't be achieved using CSS alone](http://easings.net/#easeOutBounce) and is a thing only jQuery can do. Again, your answer is perfect for the question that's been asked. This is mainly an afterthought.

Comment: @ClarusDignus You can have custom CSS transition easings: https://matthewlein.com/ceaser/

Comment: @ClarusDignus But for that specific easing, yes it does seem like you'd need to use `@keyframes`. But I'd still strongly suggest using that rather than any JS-based solutions.

Comment: Your method is so much less cumbersome than splitting styling between my style and script documents, especially when pedantically testing something as subtle as the nuances of animation. Thanks for a complete and multi-dimensional answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use jQuery's `"toggle"` keyword in the animation

```js
$("a.language_selected").on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('ul.language_dropdown').animate({ top: "toggle", opacity: "toggle"}, 'fast');
});
```

```css
.language_dropdown {
    top : 58px;
    opacity : 1;
    position: relative;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="language_selected">Click to toggle !</a>
<br />
<ul class="language_dropdown">
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>test</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Does this approach assume/require that the starting top position is 0px? E.g. What it the starting top position was 78px instead instead of 0px? I.e. Animating from 78px to 58px rather than 0px to 58px.

Comment: It assumes that when you toggle, you go from something, like `58px` to zero, and then back again. If you want to animate between given numbers, you'd have to actually give those numbers, jQuery can't guess them.